# How to migrate from Spring DI to OSGi DI in a nice manner?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I have a `Swing` project using `Spring` for DI and now I am trying to migrate to `Eclipse 4` and `OSGi`.
Using the configuration files of `Spring` the user could comment/uncomment beans in order to add/remove functionality (offered by these back-end beans).
Now in `Eclipse` and `OSGi` I am looking for the best way to do this based on `OSGi`.
I know that I can make the beans as services and define start levels in `OSGi` but this does not solve my use case, which is:
The application starts *without* these beans/modules running and if the user updates the configuration from the running UI these beans/modules start and they are also started on the next start-up of the application.
Is there a nice/clean approach for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [Eclipse Gemini Blueprint](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/) to do the management of how everything is integrated between Spring and OSGi (Gemini Blueprint is the successor to Spring Dynamic Modules). In particular, it can handle virtually all the complexity relating to dynamic service registration for you; your beans can remain virtually identical.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use Declarative Services together with Configuration Admin to let configuration data determine which services to activate. [In more detail here](http://njbartlett.name/2010/07/19/factory-components-in-ds.html).

Answer (score 0):

Like you already found out services are a good aproach to this. Simply install all your modules but do not start them. Then your UI can start and stop modules as the user selects the functionality he wants. THe OSGi framework then remembers the installed and started modules on a restart.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best approach for this is Declarative Services (DS). DS is integrated with OSGi's Configuration Admin, making it trivial to control the number of service instances as well as their configuration and service properties. For example, the following component (with the bnd annotations [which will resemble similar functionality in the OSGi specs soon]):

```
    @Component(designateFactory=Config.class)
    public MyComp implements MyService {
       interface Config {
         int port();
         String host();
      }
      Config config;
      @Activate
      void activate(Map<String,Object> map) {
        config = Configurable.createConfigurable(Config.class,map);
        start();
      }

      void foo() { ... do the MyService stuff ... }

      @Reference
      void setDataSource( DataSource ds ) { ... }
   }
```

This component requires a Configuration Admin *factory* configuration. The best way to see how powerful this is, is to setup a framework with Apache Felix Webconsole. The `designateFactory=Config.class` tells bnd to create a *metatype* XML file in the bundle. This is used by the Webconsole to create a pretty nice looking form for the configuration data, derived from the interface and its methods. This form is type aware, i.e. you cannot enter a non-nummeric value for the port number. Through the webconsole you can now instantiate multiple components by creating multiple factory configurations. Deleting these factory configurations, removes the service. In your application, you can manipulate Configuration Admin yourself under the control of the user.

Another advantage is that through Configuration Admin you can control the binding of the component's dependencies. In the aforementioned example, you can set the `dataSource.target` property to a filter  like `(db=accounting)` to select the accounting database. All configuration properties are added as service properties so you can easily set the 'db' service property on the configuration that creates the Data Source (if it was implemented this way).

This is one of the least understood advantages of DS, and I can tell you it is HUGE. To get started with this this, just create a DS project in bndtools and then a new Run Descriptor and select the Webconsole template.

Another advantage of DS is that it is small and it is not try to hide the dynamics, which in Blueprint can be painful.